# Nvidia problem with linux

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nouveau, kali

I have tried to install ubuntu multiple times but every time it had some kind of problem with my graphics card i cant lower the brightness in Ubuntu 14.4 LTS and in 17 it doesn't even load the installation screen it gives me a black screen with an error related to nouveau also i tried installing kali and has the same problem. I installed both kali and ubuntu on vmware and they work perfectly fine but i cant install them beside windows why is that? My graphics is Nvidia gtx 950m